# socketcluster create app error

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, socketcluster

I am trying to create a socketcluster app.

I followed the initial step mentioned on their site and installed socketcluster npm module globally.

But when I try creating a socketcluster app, it gives me the following error. Please help!

```
        /usr/local/lib/node_modules/socketcluster/bin/cli.js:67
      ]).then((answers) => {
                         ^
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token >
        at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
        at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
        at startup (node.js:119:16)
        at node.js:902:3
```

Comment: What version of node.js are you running? `node -v`

Answer (score 1):

The version of node installed was giving the error. The version installed was v0.10, updating to v4.6.2 resolved the error.